# How to invoke multiple methods in mockito spy in java

Tags: java, mockito

Say I have a java class like so

```
public class UnderTest {
   public void method1() { 
      callRealMethod();
  }
}
```

I want to create a spy object and modify the behavior of the method.  I found a code example for doing it in in groovy using the Spock testing framework like this:

```
UnderTest underTest = Spy() {
      method1() >> {
        callRealMethod()
        timesExecuted++
      }
}
```

How can I do that in Java instead of Spock/Groovy?

Comment: Do you want to count calls or do something else?

Comment: Yes, just to count calls

Comment: It should be noted that the [official documentation](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy-T-) pretty much recommends not using spys at all: "Real spies should be used carefully and occasionally, for example when dealing with legacy code."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use eg `Mockito` to count invocation count.

```
UnderTest spiedInstance=Mockito.spy(realInstance)

verify(spiedInstance,times(x)).method1();
```